# jQuery GeoComplete: How can I access the map object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the GeoComplete jQuery plugin:
https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/blob/master/jquery.geocomplete.js

I am initializing it as in this example, and it works fine:
http://ubilabs.github.com/geocomplete/examples/draggable.html

I want to be able to access the created Google map instance to have more control, for example, to display an InfoWindow after marker drag, etc.

In the geocomplete script, the map is initialized like this:

```
...
this.map = new google.maps.Map(
    $(this.options.map)[0],
    this.options.mapOptions
);
...
```

Can I access the `this.map` object from within my script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#selector").geocomplete('map')
```

....returns the `google.maps.Map`-instance